# Проблема с редактированием текстового файла в C++

Tags: c++

Вот, собственно, задание: 
[image: ТЗ]
И если с удалением лишних пробелов я более-менее как справился, то вот с добавлением пробела после знака препинания и с тире, дефисом у меня явные проблемы (я просто даже не представляю, как это можно реализовать). Пробовал определять тире через if...else, но ничего из этого не вышло.
Вот мой код на данный момент:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string DelSpaces(string s)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
    {
        if (s[j] == ' ')
        {
            while (s[j + 1] == ' ') s.erase(j + 1, 1);
        }
    }
    if (s[0] == ' ') s.erase(0, 1);
    if (s[s.length() - 1] == ' ') s.erase(s.length() - 1, 1);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    ifstream F("C:\\Это папка\\Бейсбол.txt", ios::in);
    string a;

    while (getline(F, a))
    {

        a = DelSpaces(a);
        cout << " " << a << endl;

    }
    F.close();
    cin.get();
}
```

Вот сам текстовый файл ( а точнее то, что там написано):
[image: Текстовый файл]

Результат работы программы:
[image: Результат работы]

Используя if...else пробовал написать нечто подобное:

```
if ('--')
    {
        cout << ' - ';
    }
    else if (' -' || '-' || '- ')
    {
        cout << ' - ';
    }
```

Очень рассчитываю на вашу помощь. Заранее всех благодарю.

Comment: ifstream F("C:\\Это папка\\Бейсбол.txt", ios::in); - абсолютные пути - плохо, Вместо цикла по строке - лучше дергать std::find или std::string::find() или find_if